# Backbone: Synchronize several Collections for the View

Tags: backbone.js

Help me please to solve my problem. The problem is: I have one view - representation of some information about folks. In my view I need information from **two** collections: `Regions` and `Cities` - because all of them have that fields.

What is the right way for doing this? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practise would be to create two separate child views for each collection and then go from there. Views are only meant to deal with one model/collection at a time, so have your parent view create the views for the city and region information and call the rendering of each of these views so that you're able to track each separate object effectively.

This is a good example of how the advantages that backbone gives you end up acting as a constraint.

Comment: I made this way yesterday :) I have heard that view can contain more than one view and model. But I don't know how to do this.. Though `options`. But how...